# 'Field does not exist. Check spelling' for field inserted via 'Insert Field'

Tags: formula, reporting, bucket

I am trying to create a win% report for a custom object we have
`Implementation_Process__c`
with Stage field `Stage__c`

I am trying to count the # of records where Stage = "Live" and where Stage = "Lost", to get to win% = Live / (Live + Lost). I've tried following [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/id4oeg/if_function_in_a_row_level_formula_that_contains/) and also [tried this post using bucket fields](https://www.asagarwal.com/salesforce-report-how-to-use-bucket-field-in-formula-field/) but I am constantly running into this error where SF is complaining that an existing field doesn't exist.

Attempt at a formula for 'Count of Records in Live':

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(CONTAINS(Implementation_Process__c.Stage__c, "Live")),
    1,
    0
)
```

Validating this formula yields the error

> Warning:
> Field Implementation_Process__c.Stage__c does not exist. Check spelling.

Bucket columns: [image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us your bucket fields as well as the formula that you've made so far? It may help to include the bucket fields as an image, but please include the formula as text instead of taking a screenshot of it. Text is more accessible and makes it easier for other people to correct small mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. I've updated the post with more details.

Comment: Maybe check your field-level security settings for that field too. If you happen to have deployed this field from a sandbox to a production environment, you might have forgotten to add the profile permissions for that.

Comment: It was a permissions error, smh. Thank you both!